# visual studio 2017 publish asp.net core

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 15.3.2 and rather old project made in dotnet core 1.1.

If I publish my project in console using 'dotnet publish ....' It works perfectly.

But when I use Visual Studio, I can restore, build, run my project absolutely without problems. Only an issue I have when I try to publish using 'Publish..' context menu in the project. I publish the project simply into the folder.

Once I make publishing I have suddenly a error and cannot assembly a project.
Here is a error I have:

```
System.InvalidCastException: [A]NuGet.ProjectModel.LockFile cannot be cast to [B]NuGet.ProjectModel.LockFile. Type A originates from 'NuGet.ProjectModel, Version=4.3.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\tools\net46\NuGet.ProjectModel.dll'. Type B originates from 'NuGet.ProjectModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\tools\net46\NuGet.ProjectModel.dll'.


  at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.LockFileCache.GetLockFile(String path)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Help needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is:

Simply delete/rename global.json file from your Core 2.0 project :) .

Comment: global.json is deprecated, that was part of older dotnet core tooling, it is dead and should be deleted along with .xproj files

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
In global.json change sdk version for:

```
"sdk": { "version": "2.0.0" },
```