# [A]NuGet.ProjectModel.LockFile cannot be cast to [B]NuGet.ProjectModel.LockFile

Tags: angular, .net-core

I am getting this error when I try to publish my .net core web application. When I run my application, it works fine. This happens only when I try to publish

```
[A]NuGet.ProjectModel.LockFile cannot be cast to [B]NuGet.ProjectModel.LockFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `global.json` from your Core project.

- More info:
  [visual studio 2017 publish asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920532/visual-studio-2017-publish-asp-net-core)